# Specify path to an file in a .plist

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, plist

The image file `afghanistan.png` is located in a Group called Flags within the Resources Group of an iOS project. I want to access this image in a UITableViewCell. When I call it, it returns `(null)`. Is

```
<string>/Flags/afghanistan.png</string>
```

the correct path to the file?

```
<plist version="1.0">
<array>
    <dict>
        <key>name</key>
        <string>Afghanistan</string>
        <key>government</key>
        <string>Islamic Republic</string>
        <key>population</key>
        <integer>0</integer>
        <key>image</key>
        <string>/Flags/afghanistan.png</string>
    </dict>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bear in mind that the *Grouping* of files within an Xcode project is only a virtual "directory", not a real one.

With that in mind, you will probably find that the image is not in a /Flags directory at all, but rather in the root directory (or another completely different one).  Try changing it just to

```
<key>image</key>
<string>afghanistan.png</string>
```

Also, remember that iPhone is case sensitive and Mac isn't!  This can lead to things working in the simulator but not on the phone...

Answer (score 2):

If your trying to access this file from your project code, the correct path would be something like:

```
NSString *filePath = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath] stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Flags/afghanistan.png"];
```

This of course assumes that the file is actually in the right place. In the .plist file, you'd probably be better off using the full path, something like: /Users/username/MyApp/Resources/Flags/afghanistan.png or whatever your path might be.